# Serieal Workflow Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, content-approval

I have an old Sharepoint (2010) approval workflow that is going away on our cloud Sharepoint so I want to use Power Automate to recreate it.  I do not seem to be able to accomplish this using any of the out of box templates and am over my head.  Is there any way to accomplich this without coding?  Thanks so much in advance!

The steps to the workflow are:

1. User selects a file in a Sharepoint doc library and initiates the flow
2. User prompted to select Sharepoint users to be the approvers (I presume I need to use PowerApps to allow the initiator to pick the list?).  Also a text field they can enter in any comments/notes, a date field for putting in a due date.
   a.  The order is important and needs to be sequential.
3. An approver may appear twice, e.g. User A,->User B->User C->User A.  This is important. Approver #1 receives an email with a link to the file and any notes the initiator put in.  They can open the link and edit/comment (if an office doc) or if a pdf, they can download it, mark it up in Acrobat, and replace the original file.  They then approve it.  No need for a rejection option, as it is more an opportunity to comment, not reject it outright.  They then approve the document, and should be able to have a place to add any comments.
4. Approver #2 received an email with a link to the doc as well as the comments from the previous reviewer or reviewers.
5. Repeat until all approvers have approved
6. When all Approved, the initiator receives an email it is complete along with all comments gathered along the way, including who made the comments.

Some other features needed:
•   If an approval step is not addressed within 24 hours, a reminder email needs to be sent.
•   Needs a place to see where the flow is, i.e. who has approved, who has not.  Not sure how this works in the Power Automate world.
•   Ability for anyone to reassign a task, for example one of the approvers is out
•   That this flow could be run from any doc library site-wide.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to reconsider in this process:

1. It is not possible to modify the file during the Approval process since every modification would trigger a new Approval logically. The flow needs to be stopped while you make the second change.
2. The ability to reassign the approval task is only available in the management dashboard. See a related post here: ["Reassign " button in Start an approval action.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/quot-Reassign-quot-button-in-Start-an-approval-action/td-p/362844)
3. It is not supported to select or change the next approver during the flow process (same reason as above). You can either use a column with multiple person values or manually assign the approvers in the flow.
4. You can see the approvers’ activities also via *Power Automate > Action items > Approvals > Request Item > Activity*.